# Matchmaking not showing matches in Unity3d development HUD

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, matchmaking

I'm not sure why matches are not showing up in the HUD.  If both clients are on the same computer, the match shows up, but not if they are on separate computers, whether or not they are on the same network.  I'm following this tutorial:  [Multiplayer matchmaking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9Ra0D7JJ88&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5PhGqsO7G4PsbEC_Al-kPZ&index=17).  I checked with others having the same problem on different threads but I can't get any solutions to work.

I disabled all firewalls and still had the same result, so it can't be that.

If this is a common error, then is there a solution that actually works?

Comment: ok - I changed the data center from mm.unet.unity3d.com to us1-mm.unet.unity3d.com.  This actually worked.  I don't know why it works but it looks as though two instances on different computers use different data centers.  Don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

ok - I changed the data center from mm.unet.unity3d.com to us1-mm.unet.unity3d.com. This actually worked. I don't know why it works but it looks as though two instances on different computers use different data centers. Don't know why though.